# How create voxel 3d (x,y,z,attribute) in GRASS GIS from CSV file

Tags: grass-gis, csv, 3d, grass-7.0, voxel

I have a csv file with (x,y,z,attribute) x,y,z,attribute are float value, and I want to do a voxel 3D in Grass Gis, the documentation and examples are poor, so please I need some help.
I am using Grass Version 8.2.1

[image]

I used v.in.ascii in Grass Gis using X,Y,Z columns and without CAT field, and I can see my dataset in 2D View, but in 3D view my dataset are in 2D (without elevation).

[image]

Comment: Please comment on where to improve the documentation: which page(s) concretely?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this Wiki page:

https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Voxel#Import_or_creation_of_volumes
You can import 3D ASCII raster data in GRASS voxel format using [r3.in.ascii](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/r3.in.ascii.html) or [r3.in.xyz](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/r3.in.xyz.html).

Comment: I have Grass GIS 8.2.1 and 7.8.7, stable version on Windows, but I can't see the r3.in.xyz command, could You please tell me what Grass version are you using?

Comment: In this link I have my dataset, there is no sensitive information https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vinHKN5pH-HMHhwRYH9YMEbEJFAE1IU6?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you try the command console for r3.in.xyz? Not all commands are in the menu (there would be too many).

Comment: You are right, I used the r3.in.xyz in the console, I loaded the dataset, and grass did a 3draster, but I can't see the result in the 2D or 3D display, I don't know if this problem is about my PC o my dataset?. Excuseme, could you please to load my dataset in your computer?, because I need to know if i have a problem, or I am doing something wrong

Comment: I appreciate if someone can load my data (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vinHKN5pH-HMHhwRYH9YMEbEJFAE1IU6) in Grass to see the information in voxel3D, so I can rule out if my problem is related to my computer, or the form that I am using Grass Gis. I hope some help